# why am i getting an error SyntaxError : invalid syntax for this code

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

This is a code in python which calculates `f (x) =∑ ((-1)*x)/(x*x+n*n)`
n from 1 to infinite....
correct to 0.0001, for the range 1 < x < 100 in steps of 0.1.
But i am getting an syntax error, as i am new to programming in python...

```
    from scipy import *
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    x=arange(0.1,100,0.1)
    f=zeros(len(x))
    s=-1
    for n in range (1,10000):
        t=s*x/(x*x+n*n)
        f +=t
        s =-s
        if max(abs(t))< 1e-4
            break
    for xx in c_[x,f]:
        print "%f    %f" % (xx[0],xx[1])
```

Comment: What's the exact syntax error?

Comment: Which syntax error are you getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add `:` after `if max(abs(t))< 1e-4`